# Questions regarding concurrent connections limit to MC SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, sftp

We've noticed there is a limitation of 10 concurrent connections to MC SFTP according to the following doc:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_enhanced_ftp_guide.htm&type=5

We would like to use more than 10 concurrent connections:

- Will adding a new FTP user allow us to do so? In other words is the
  limit is per ftp user or per ftp site?
- If not - what other options will allow us to use to more than 10
  concurrent connections? (For example: should we buy a new BU for that?)

Finally a side question: is the 10 concurrent connections limit refers to tcp control connections? or tcp data connections?

Appreciate any help,

Barak

Comment: What is the use case where you need more than 10 concurrent connections?